# 8085 SIM instruction don't care bit

Tags: microprocessor, 8085

While reading about the SIM in 8085 i came upon the accumulator state at the data pin 5 where when SIM instruction is executed we have to consider pin 5 of the accumulator to be don't care.
So I am not able to understand why do we need to define or mention about a don't care bit while processing the SIM instruction execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In defining interfaces between hardware and software (because that's what the SIM - Set Interrupt Mask instruction does), it is good practice to tell the user, the programmer, what all the bits mean, and what they do, or don't do, so that the programmer doesn't have to guess.

Comment: no but i wanted to know why we even need a dont care bit in SIM

Comment: It's not that you need it, but the fact that that bit is there anyway.  The 8085 is an 8-bit machine.  All the registers in it are inherently 8-bits wide.  In this case they only needed 7 bits for the SIM function.  The hardware designer is just telling the programmer that they don't have to worry about the value of that one unused bit.

Comment: thank you for answering my query

Comment: You're welcome.